bluetooth headphones have strange chirp
I have some strange sounds like chirp stopping and starting the audio again, several times a second
I have LG-GRAM 17 with kernel 6.9.2-1 and Gnome
bluetoothctl
Agent registeredct to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]#         WH-1000XM5

status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-06-05 19:39:32 EEST; 29min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1249 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38135)
     Memory: 2.9M (peak: 3.9M)
        CPU: 93ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1249 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/faststream
Jun 05 19:39:33 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Jun 05 19:42:49 radu-gram bluetoothd[1249]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_80_0A_F2_CF_FB/sep3/fd0: fd(33) ready


Well don't know if this is the solution, but I switched to PipeWire and works ok now.
